# How to find special characters in Linux Vim

Tags: vim, search, find, vi, utf-8

I want to find special characters in a text file. It is known that the UTF-8 encoded file contains

```
Chinese characters , 
"-", 
"^A"(control-A, which is one of special characters), 
numbers, 
alphabets, and 
some other characters. <- This is what I want to find out.
```

I'm using Vim in Linux to find other special characters.

I used

```
/[^^A0-9a-zA-Z-]
```

to find that, but this will also show Chinese characters. How do filter Chinese characters and show only the other special characters in the file?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447561/vim-how-to-search-replace-special-chars

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode codepoint range for *CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPHS* is `0x4E00-0x9FFF`; you'd have to exclude that range of characters from your `[...]` collection (probably using the `\%uNNNN` regular expression atom).

Unfortunately, [Vim currently cannot search for ranges larger than 256 characters](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/299aa3d757293f26/d33a7180c434a6c1?lnk=gst&q=%5Cu+unicode+range#d33a7180c434a6c1), so you'd have to combine multiple collections (`[...]\|[...]\|[...]\|...`), or choose a different approach.